# Android: Custom ListAdapter extending BaseAdapter crashes on application launch

Tags: android

Data being pulled from a local DB, then mapped using a cursor. Custom Adapter displays data similar to a ListView. As items are added/deleted from the DB, the adapter is supposed to refresh. The solution attempted below crashes the application at launch. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
-D

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   View v = convertView;
   ViewGroup p = parent;            
   if (v == null) {
     LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_row, p);
   }
   int size = mAdapter.getCount();
   Log.d(TAG, "position " + position + " Size " + size);
   if(size != 0){
     if(position < size) return mAdapter.getView(position, v, p);
     Log.d(TAG, "-position " + position + " Size " + size);
   }
   return null;
 }
```

Exception:

```
03-23 00:14:10.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
03-23 00:14:10.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718):     at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:461)
03-23 00:14:10.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
03-23 00:14:10.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
03-23 00:14:10.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
03-23 00:14:10.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(718):     at com.xyz.abc.CustomSeparatedListAdapter.getView(CustomSeparatedListAdapter.java:90)
...
```

Answer (score 87):

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_row, p);
```

Add a `false` third parameter to that call, and I think your problem will go away. The call should become:

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_row, p, false);
```

Comment: This is the answer!  I had this issue already but I'd forgotten to put in the extra false parameter this time since it's been a while and sure enough this fixed it right up.

Answer (score 7):

change this code

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_row, p);
```

to

```
v = vi.inflate(R.layout.items_row, null );
```

Comment: warning! Wrong answer. Please see http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/