# Custom Listview not displaying

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

**What I am doing:**

> I am writing an android app that has to do with maps and routes etc. On the home screen of the application , there is a button that opens the favorites page. The favorites page is comprised out of the following xml layout.

layout_favorites.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/mainscreen2">
        <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
        >
            <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
                <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewfavorites"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_width="60px"
                android:layout_height="60px"
                android:src="@drawable/android_button_44_2"/>
                <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_favorites"
                android:background="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="60px"
                android:textSize="35sp"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="Favorites"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_favorites"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            >
            </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is working fine , no worries. In the top layout , you will see there is a ListView. I want to populate that ListView with rows looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/route_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/route_image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/route_image"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route_author"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/route_title"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/route_length"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/route_title"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
     <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

So in the end , it should look something like this:

(image drawn in paint :p)
http://s9.postimage.org/cgcahc1i7/Untitled.png

OR

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/694/67362201.png/

Now, heres where the problem comes in. It does not display. I am using a custom Adapter that extends the BaseAdapter class to handle the Listview and inflate the view etc. I will post the Adapater and then the Activity for the Favorites screen.

Adapter class:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


/**
 *
 * @author Gideon
 */
public class Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites extends BaseAdapter
{
    //----------------------------------------
    //  Variables
    //----------------------------------------
        private Context context;
        private final Drawable[] drawables;
        private final String[] titles;
        private final String[] authors;
        private final String[] durations;
    //----------------------------------------

    //----------------------------------------
    //  Methods
    //----------------------------------------


        public Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites(Context context ,String[] titles,String[] authors,String[] durations,Drawable[] drawables)
        {

            this.context = context;
            this.titles = titles;
            this.authors = authors;
            this.durations = durations;
            this.drawables = drawables;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_row, parent);


                ImageView map_image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_image);
            TextView map_title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_title);
            TextView map_author = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_author);
                TextView map_length = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_length);
                ImageView map_image_arrow = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.drawable.arrow);

                map_image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawables[position]);
                map_title.setText(titles[position]);
                map_author.setText(authors[position]);
                map_length.setText(durations[position]);
                map_image_arrow.setBackgroundDrawable(map_image_arrow.getBackground());


        return rowView;
    }
        //----------------------------------------

        //----------------------------------------
        // Not Implemented
        //----------------------------------------
        public Object getItem(int arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
           return 0;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
            //----------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------
}
```

Favorites Activity Class:

```
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 *
 * @author Gideon
 */
public class Page_Favorites extends ListActivity
{
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Hierdie info sal in die toekoms vanaf die databsae moet kom of net vervang word met die database entries in for loops etc. (This info will be loaded from the database in the future)
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public final String[] map_titles = {"Route 1","Route 2","Route 3","Route 4","Route 5","Route 6"};
    public final String[] map_authors = {"Jannie","Sannie","Bennie","Kosie","Gideon","Alex"};
    public final String[] map_lengths = {"42km","2km","21.5km","8km","34km","23km"};
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.route_image_1);
    public final Drawable[] map_images = {iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground()};
    //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        overridePendingTransition(R.layout.animation_fadein, R.layout.animation_fadeout);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_favorites);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_favorites);
        list.setAdapter(new Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites(this, map_titles, map_authors, map_lengths, map_images));

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
               Toast.makeText(Page_Favorites.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When I click on the button to launch the favorites screen/activity and create the listview , the application exits with an error (was forced to quit ...). Any help or ideas will be appreciated. Thx.

**EDIT:**

Adb Log Errors:

```
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{RedPheasant.LoggerApp/RedPheasant.LoggerApp.Page_Favorites}: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at RedPheasant.LoggerApp.Page_Favorites.onCreate(Page_Favorites.java:48)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
22:54:21.505    24082   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      ... 11 more
22:54:21.515    212 ERROR   #212        Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Also , fixed this part :

```
public int getCount()
    {
       if(titles == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return titles.length;
    }
```

still getting the same problem.
**EDIT 2:**

Ok guys, thx for all the help so far...

I have furthermore changed this:

The new Favorites Page activity (modified):

```
public class Page_Favorites extends Activity
{




    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        overridePendingTransition(R.layout.animation_fadein, R.layout.animation_fadeout);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_favorites);
        // ToDo add your GUI initialization code here

        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //Hierdie info sal in die toekoms vanaf die databsae moet kom of net vervang word met die database entries in for loops etc.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


        String[] map_titles = {"Route 1","Route 2","Route 3","Route 4","Route 5","Route 6"};
        String[] map_authors = {"Jannie","Sannie","Bennie","Kosie","Gideon","Alex"};
        String[] map_lengths = {"42km","2km","21.5km","8km","34km","23km"};
        //ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.route_image_1);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.route_image_1);
        Drawable[] map_images = {d,d,d,d,d,d};
        Drawable d2 = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow);
       //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_favorites);
        list.setAdapter(new Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites(this, map_titles, map_authors, map_lengths, map_images,d2));//lika a boss itches

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
            {
               Toast.makeText(Page_Favorites.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The new Adapter class (modified):

```
public class Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites extends BaseAdapter
{
    //----------------------------------------
    //  Variables
    //----------------------------------------
        private Context context;
        private final Drawable[] drawables;
        private final String[] titles;
        private final String[] authors;
        private final String[] durations;
        private final Drawable d;
    //----------------------------------------

    //----------------------------------------
    //  Methods
    //----------------------------------------


        public Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites(Context context ,String[] titles,String[] authors,String[] durations,Drawable[] drawables,Drawable d)
        {

            this.context = context;
            this.titles = titles;
            this.authors = authors;
            this.durations = durations;
            this.drawables = drawables;
            this.d = d;
        }
        //----------------------------------------


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_row, parent);


                ImageView map_image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_image);
        TextView map_title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_title);
        TextView map_author = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_author);
                TextView map_length = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_length);

                ImageView map_image_arrow = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_arrow);

                map_image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawables[position]);
                map_title.setText(titles[position]);
                map_author.setText(authors[position]);
                map_length.setText(durations[position]);
                map_image_arrow.setBackgroundDrawable(d);


        return rowView;
    }
        //----------------------------------------

        //----------------------------------------
        // Not Implemented
        //----------------------------------------
        public Object getItem(int arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position)
        {
           return 0;
        }

        public int getCount()
        {
           if(titles == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return titles.length;
        }
            //----------------------------------------
    //----------------------------------------
}
```

And the new error log adblog:

```
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:461)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:416)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at RedPheasant.LoggerApp.Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites.getView(Adapter_Maplist_Page_Favorites.java:73)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1554)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1793)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:718)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:775)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1646)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1384)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7228)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1147)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1867)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
23:15:15.839    24746   ERROR   RedPheasant.LoggerApp   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
23:15:15.849    212 ERROR   #212        Dumpstate > /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
```

Thx for the help so far... still getting the same error though.

**Update:**

I'm guessing this is my main problem right now:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
```

I'm guessing this has something to do with the Adapter that does not support the view. I am somewhat confused :p lol. Any ideas.

**FINAL EDIT - SOLVED**
Thx for all the help guys. Its finally working and it looks great.

The main problems where the way I assigned the drawables to the ImageViews which caused problems when doing the inflate. Thx Sam for pointing that out. Another major problem was that I had to add the false parameter to the inflate method to not copy it to the root. Thx Angelo for pointing this out.

Comment: If "the application exits with an error", please post your LogCat.

Comment: `at RedPheasant.LoggerApp.Page_Favorites.onCreate(Page_Favorites.java:48)
` Tells us there is a null pointer exception on line 48 which is in Page_Favorites.onCreate(). What is line 48?

Comment: line 48 is this :

 Drawable[] map_images = {iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground()};

I guess I should look at that ...

Comment: You cannot load drawable like this: `findViewById(R.drawable.route_image_1);` which makes `iv` null. I'll update my answer with a solution to this.

Comment: Thx ! I will check for the solution. I changed it , now I no longer get a nullpointer exception but something else. Will post the update soon. thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the LogCat we can only guess at what errors you have...

**1)** You are extending a ListActivity:

```
public class Page_Favorites extends ListActivity
```

This **requires** that you have a ListView with the attribute `android:id="@android:id/list"` in the layout that you pass to setContentView(). I simply recommend you only extend an Activity:

```
public class Page_Favorites extends Activity
```

since your current code does not depend on a ListActivity.

**2)** Out of context:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.route_image_1);
public final Drawable[] map_images = {iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground(),iv.getBackground()};
```

You cannot reference findViewById() before you have created the Activity, this should be done in onCreate() after setContentView().

**3)** You should load your drawable into an ImageView like this:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewfavorites);
iv.setImageResource(R.drawables.route_image_1);
```

I guessed at where you wanted the image... Is this what you meant to do?

And enough people have commented on getCount() already, so I won't reiterate it.

**4)** In your adapter's getView(), change this:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_row, parent);
```

to this:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_row, parent, false);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have changed the extend to Activity. Still get the same problem.

Comment: Please copy & paste your LogCat errors into the question. In Eclipse, Window -> Show View -> LogCat

Comment: Also changed the ImageView declaration to after the onCreate method .. after setContentView(). Still get the same problem. thx for the help so far!

Comment: @Janpan I believe the error is in another line now if you made that changes. Can you point us out the new line of the error?

Comment: I updated my answer with how to load drawables into an existing ImageView.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Would it be fine if I load the image as follows:
ImageView map_image = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_image);

map_image.setImageDrawable(drawables[position]);

Comment: That appears correct, as long as `drawables[position]` is a integer id (like, `R.drawable.route_image_1`);

Comment: yes it is , thx. see the update above. Getting closer to the solution. Thx for the help !

Comment: I added a suggestion for the UnsupportedOperationException error.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have the *getCount()* method, which should return a int value throwing an exception? That seems preety awkward. Instead of you should do:

```
public int getCount()
{
    return yourDataArray.size();
}
```

That method is responsible for the number of lines that your ListView will going to have, ie, if *yourDataArray* has a size = 7 this means you will have 7 lines in the ListView.

**EDIT:**

Here is your solution:

1. Replace getItem() method with:

   ```
    public Object getItem(int arg0)
    {
        return arg0;
    }
   ```
2. Replace your adapter getView() method with the code below.

   ```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       View v = convertView;
       ViewHolder holder;

       if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = vi.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_row, null);

            ImageView map_image = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_image);
            TextView map_title = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_title);
            TextView map_author = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_author);
            TextView map_length = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_length);
            ImageView map_image_arrow = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.route_arrow);

           v.setTag(holder);
       }
       else {
           holder=(ViewHolder)v.getTag();
       }

       /** Define here the values to all the Views of the ViewHolder. */
       holder.map_image.setBackgroundDrawable(drawables[position]);
       holder.map_title.setText(titles[position]);
       holder.map_author.setText(authors[position]);
       holder.map_length.setText(durations[position]);
       holder.map_image_arrow.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

   return v;
   }
   ```

   Use a ViewHolder. Be sure you define a ViewHolder inner class like:

   ```
   public static class ViewHolder {
         public TextView map_image ;
         public TextView map_title;
         public TextView map_author;
         public TextView map_length;
         public ImageView map_image_arrow;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Check this method:

```
public int getCount()
        {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
```

Return value that's > 0. It helped me recently. I'm not sure about your problem, but just try.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Fixed that part but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

```
public int getCount()
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
```

You should return the number of elements in the list. Something like this:

```
public int getCount()
    {
        if(title == null) {
           return 0;
        }
        return title.length;
    }
```

Also, what Sam said is another issue you should fix.

**EDIT** Seeing your adapter code i noticed that you are not using a `ViewHolder`. I strongly reccomend you to use it since it can leverage the performance of your listView significantly. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) is a nice link that explains all the basics about a listView. The above comment is just for performance but it is good to include it.

From the answer with the highest score of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496698/android-custom-listadapter-extending-baseadapter-crashes-on-application-launch). Change this line:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_row, parent);
```

with this:

```
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_favorites_row, parent, false);
```

and i think you will not have any problem.

Comment: Thank You for the reply! I fixed this , but still get the same error.

Comment: This fixed it ! , along with all the stuff from Sam's responses. Thx guys , will update ! Thx a lot.